# $http.post call inside another $http.post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I want to make an `$http.post` inside another `$http.post` as the second one is dependant on the first. Basically what I'm doing is:

```
$http.post("/my/server/location").then(function (response) {
    $http.post("/my/second/api/call/"+response.data.number).then(function (response) {
      $scope.message = "Created successfully";
    }, function (response){
      $scope.message = "Could not create";
    });

    //Create modal from response.data received from first API Call
    //Add $scope.message to this modal.
    });
```

What's happening as you would have guessed is the second one stays pending until the initial promise is returned, and I want to show `$scope.message` in the modal which is hence, not possible. While I understand why that's happening, I can't seem to figure how to get around that. I tried dealing with `$q` but made a mess out of it. Any help will be gladly appreciated.

Comment: So the issue is that $scope.message is only being defined after the second api call returns? And you want it after the first call returns?

Comment: Yes exactly. @CameronRodriguez

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To **chain** the message use a [return statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) in both the success handler and the rejection handler of the second XHR:

```
$http.post("/my/server/location").then(function (response1) {
    return $http.post("/my/second/api/call/"+response1.data.number)
      .then(function (response2) {
        $scope.message = "Created successfully";
        return $scope.message;
    }).catch(function (errorResponse2) {
        $scope.message = "Could not create";
        return $scope.message;
    }).then(function(message) {

        //Create modal from response1.data received from first API Call
        //Add `message` from the second XHR to this modal.

        return [response1.data, message];
    });
});
```

The [return statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) in the `.catch` rejection handler converts the rejected promise to a success which is handled by the next `.then` method in the chain.

The final promise returns an array which has both the data from the first XHR and the message from the second XHR.

> ### Chaining Promises
>
> Because calling the `.then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises.
>
> It is possible to create chains of any length and since **a promise can be resolved with another promise** (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs.
>
> [— AngularJS $q Service API Reference - Chaining Promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)

Comment: This answer fits best with my API. Works like a charm. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

You're right, `$q` won't help here unless you want both promises to be executed at once and then wait for both of their responses.

Here you want to execute one promise then the other, which according to your code looks fine. However, anything you want to do after the second promise has executed needs to be done in that `.then()` block.

Example:

```
$http.post("/my/server/location").then(function (response) {
    $http.post("/my/second/api/call/"+response.data.number).then(function (response) {
       $scope.message = "Created successfully";
       // Create modal from response.data received from first API Call
    }, function (error){
        $scope.message = "Could not create";
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ben but this will not work. The second API will not always return a 200. It depends on the user input. So the workflow is -> First API returns 200 -> second API if returns 200, then store success message, else store failure message -> Create modal with data from first API and append message from second API.

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.post("/my/server/location")
 .then(function (response) {

    $http.post("/my/second/api/call/"+response.data.number).then(function 
      (response) {

     }, function (response){

     });

    $scope.message = "Created successfully";

     //Create modal from response.data received from first API Call
    //Add $scope.message to this modal.
    $scope.buildModal(response.data);

})
.catch(function(error){
    $scope.message = "Could not create";
    $scope.buildModal();
})
```

So the issue with what you had was that `$scope.message = "Created successfully";` was locked in the nested api call. By taking it out of that you can build your modal immediately after the first api call. In the code above, nothing is waiting for the second api call to finish because nothing is in its `.then` block

I moved the modal building to a separate function `buildModal` because it has to be called both from the `.then` and the `.catch` block

Comment: Thanks Cameron but this will not work. `$scope.message` is not the error output of the first API call but the second.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```js
var fn = {
    test: function() {
        return $http.post("/my/server/location");
    }
};

fn.test().success(function(response) {
  $http.post("/my/second/api/call/"+response.data.number).then(function (response) {
      $scope.message = "Created successfully";
    }, function (response){
      $scope.message = "Could not create";
      }
});
```

Comment: `success` has been deprecated for some time.